# How to use gulp to serve and livereload a NPM package

Tags: npm, gulp, localhost, livereload, serve

I have created an npm package that creates an HTML document inside the current working directory from where I am calling that particular command described in the bin of that npm package.

The command is `generate_doc`, it will fetch all the data from the current working directory and create the resultant html inside the same directory as "newindex.html".

I want this particular file newindex.html to be served on a localhost port when I type `generate_doc serve`, the command gets executed and the .html file is served in the localhost. I have heard that gulp will be the best option for this but I am confused about where to start with.

Even a small help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You need [gulp-webserver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-webserver) package for this. [Read this article](https://medium.com/objects-in-space/considering-a-static-site-tool-learn-gulp-2fd5f9821fc4#.uex3q7cwy) to get started with gulp.

Comment: Thanks for the link for the article, but even that does not serve my requirement. I want to call `generate_doc serve` from terminal as a command line argument while inside a particular working directory, and I could not get any such gulp plugin for this, could you please help..